# JAVA - How to change JTable row color after clicking on it?

Tags: java, colors, jtable

I 'm a Java beginner.
I create an application with a JTable which is populated with a database.
In my database I have some 'news'. In my JTable I display titles of 'news' and when an user click on a row, it display a popup with the right contents of the news.
But I want to colorize the cell which are 'read' when the user clicked on it.

I use my own TableModel.

I hope I'm clear...

If I need to put some code, tell me what please...

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Post the minimal code necessary to frame the confusion you are trying to work through (i.e. so someone can see precisely where you need help).

Comment: Implement the table cell renderer and change the color of the component used for rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class JTableTest extends JFrame {

    private JTable      table;
    private int         col;
    private int         rowz;


    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public JTableTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        /** any other components */

        table = new JTable();//create the table
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new CustomModel());
        table.addMouseListener(new CustomListener());
    }

    public class CustomListener extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            super.mouseClicked(arg0);
            //get the clicked cell's row and column
            rowz = table.getSelectedRow();
            col = table.getSelectedColumn();

            // Repaints JTable
            table.repaint();
        }
    }

    public class CustomModel extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {


        private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            Color c = Color.WHITE;//define the color you want
            if (isSelected && row == rowz & column == col)
                c = Color.GREEN;
            label.setBackground(c);
            return label;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this example of how to get the table cell on mouseClick: http://codeprogress.com/java/showSamples.php?index=52&key=JTableValueofSelectedCell

You can use this to get the selected row and column.

Then you need to create a custom TableCellRenderer, possibly as an inner class so that it can use the selected row and column data and set the background of the cell to your highlighted color